# How do I segueing to the UIViewController I'm in?

Tags: swift, segue, viewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

**I'm trying to go from one view, filled with data from an object, to the same view but filled with a different object via segue.**

Using a segue is necessary as apposed to switching the object and refreshing the view because my users need to be able to go back to the past view controller when they hit the back button.

Example:
(ThisView, with thisObject populating the view) -> (ThisView, with thisOtherObject populating the view)

What I've tried:

presentView Controller: This didn't work because it is not the default segue I'm trying to achieve.

```
let next: NewClubProfile = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("clubProfile") as! NewClubProfile
presentViewController(next, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Using Navigation Controller: Can't figure out how to segue the new object to populate the other view

```
let next: NewClubProfile = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("clubProfile") as! NewClubProfile
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(next, animated:true)
```

Comment: When doing the second approach what issue are you facing?

Comment: The second approach was actually what worked, what I was still figuring out was how to add the new object to the view controller. If you look at the answer I posted below you can see the working code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should have taken longer to solve this myself before posting this but I couldn't find an answer that fit what I needed. Anyway, solved it, here's what worked for me.

```
let next: ViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("viewName") as! ViewController
next.object = newObject
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(next, animated:true)
```